# jQuery and WCF WebService Deserialization issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, deserialization

I had a WebService in an ASMX file, however i ended up having issues with it since, under some circumstances i had too much data (Printing a paged Grid, retrieves all data). Found out that i can't configure much of anything related to message size with ASMX services, so i decided to go the WCF route to solve my issue.

Converting my existing WebService, i created an interface and the actual service and then added my configurations to my WebConfig. So far so good. After converting, i can't manage to get it to run. I have a breakpoint on the first line of my Method and it never reaches it.

Chrome gives me "400 (Bad Format)" errors on the call, so i went and configured Tracing.
In the traces, i see an exception being raised on the call of my method.

```
There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:jsonAOData. Please see InnerException for more details.
```

(Full exception, sorry in French)

```
Le serveur a rencontré une erreur lors du traitement de la demande. Le message d'exception est 'Le module de formatage a généré une exception en tentant de désérialiser le message : Une erreur s'est produite en tentant de désérialiser le paramètre http://tempuri.org/:jsonAOData. Le message InnerException était 'Une erreur s'est produite lors de la désérialisation de l'objet de type System.String. Jeton 'null' attendu, mais 'name' a été trouvé.'. Pour plus d'informations, consultez InnerException.'. Pour plus d'informations, consultez les journaux du serveur. La trace de la pile d'exception est :

à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, PartInfo returnInfo, Object& returnValue) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyCore(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) 
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Looking at the call in chrome, it specifies the following:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:2806/MyWebApp/WebServices.svc/GetRequests
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3436
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:DOKU_PREFS=list%23thumbs; ASP.NET_SessionId=bttjyzhltsrxflcn43i0v43f; MyWebApp=ECFF341038FFA20B7357CAEE592127F98B46F7421F5388A6CCB1D8460A1A66E345D82E62F634BF2854F9008DD01C875B53B3864E3EE3511AFAC67C40AE9BB4013E367D50605B326755CA7F286EF18CD7A3E229EDA2EE8066A12DC330B293AEE549322C7AADC46306CA63402A27F6F125703D070B07EE8BBDA9AC2F185CF546DDEAF1AA6AEE6B42BAFF41BDDC690CDED8
Host:localhost:2806
Origin:http://localhost:2806
Referer:http://localhost:2806/MyWebApp/Viewer.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Payload (that i validated using JSONLint):

```
{"jsonAOData": "[{"name":"sEcho","value":1},{"name":"iColumns","value":33},{"name":"sColumns","value":"FileId,StateDesc,DeptDescription,Division,ConfirmProblem,TaskDescription,GenComment,FileType,Problem,TreatmentTargetDate,TreatmentPlannedDate,Responsable,ReceivedDate,NoCiv,Generic,Streetname,StreetDirection,StreetDescription,TreatmentStartDate,TreatmentCompleteDate,TreatmentDemandDate,SiteDesc,SectorOld,District,AreaOld,IntersectStreetId,Prepose,PrintedDate,Requester,AdressC,LocationPrecision,RealisedFor,Source"},{"name":"iDisplayStart","value":0},{"name":"iDisplayLength","value":-1},{"name":"mDataProp_0","value":"FileId"},{"name":"mDataProp_1","value":"StateDesc"},{"name":"mDataProp_2","value":"DeptDescription"},{"name":"mDataProp_3","value":"Division"},{"name":"mDataProp_4","value":"ConfirmProblem"},{"name":"mDataProp_5","value":"TaskDescription"},{"name":"mDataProp_6","value":"GenComment"},{"name":"mDataProp_7","value":"FileType"},{"name":"mDataProp_8","value":"Problem"},{"name":"mDataProp_9","value":"TreatmentTargetDate"},{"name":"mDataProp_10","value":"TreatmentPlannedDate"},{"name":"mDataProp_11","value":"Responsable"},{"name":"mDataProp_12","value":"ReceivedDate"},{"name":"mDataProp_13","value":"NoCiv"},{"name":"mDataProp_14","value":"Generic"},{"name":"mDataProp_15","value":"Streetname"},{"name":"mDataProp_16","value":"StreetDirection"},{"name":"mDataProp_17","value":"StreetDescription"},{"name":"mDataProp_18","value":"TreatmentStartDate"},{"name":"mDataProp_19","value":"TreatmentCompleteDate"},{"name":"mDataProp_20","value":"TreatmentDemandDate"},{"name":"mDataProp_21","value":"SiteDesc"},{"name":"mDataProp_22","value":"SectorOld"},{"name":"mDataProp_23","value":"District"},{"name":"mDataProp_24","value":"AreaOld"},{"name":"mDataProp_25","value":"IntersectStreetId"},{"name":"mDataProp_26","value":"Prepose"},{"name":"mDataProp_27","value":"PrintedDate"},{"name":"mDataProp_28","value":"Requester"},{"name":"mDataProp_29","value":"AdressC"},{"name":"mDataProp_30","value":"LocationPrecision"},{"name":"mDataProp_31","value":"RealisedFor"},{"name":"mDataProp_32","value":"Source"},{"name":"iSortCol_0","value":0},{"name":"sSortDir_0","value":"asc"},{"name":"iSortingCols","value":1},{"name":"bSortable_0","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_1","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_2","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_3","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_4","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_5","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_6","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_7","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_8","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_9","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_10","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_11","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_12","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_13","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_14","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_15","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_16","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_17","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_18","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_19","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_20","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_21","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_22","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_23","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_24","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_25","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_26","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_27","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_28","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_29","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_30","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_31","value":true},{"name":"bSortable_32","value":true}]"}
```

For references, im also including some configurations / code snippets to help troubleshoot it :

my (partial) jQuery (DataTables) initialisation

```
sAjaxSource: "WebServices.svc/GetRequests",
fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    var jsonAOData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: sSource,
        data: '{"jsonAOData": "' + jsonAOData + '"}',
        success: function (msg) {
            fnCallback(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

My method definition in IWebServices:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
FormatedList GetRequests(string jsonAOData);
```

It's implementation (There is no attributes/decorations around it), in WebServices.cs, which WebServices.svc inherits of.

```
public FormatedList GetRequests(string jsonAOData)
{
    // My code that was working before but never gets call now.
}
```

My WebConfig

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="WebServicesBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior name="WebServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior">
            <webHttp/>
         </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServicesBehavior" name="WebServices">
         <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IWebServices" />
      </service>
   </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any idea what is it that im missing ? I'm sure im fairly close to my goal, just can't grasp the last little bit...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinkg it may have something to do with the fact that i am not specifying any namespaces. Playing around with the way im building my parameter (jsonAOData), i get different deserialization exceptions, one being :

    Élément de fin 'root' provenant de l'espace de noms '' attendu. Trouvé élément 'jsonAOData' provenant de l'espace de noms ''.'. Pour plus d'informations, consultez les journaux du serveur. 

Which means that it found 'jsonAOData' while it was looking for the namespace's root element.

Comment: As your "GetRequests" method only takes a String parameter, try to pass a simple string to it first, like `data : "Some String"`, just to make sure that's working fine. Then pass a simple JSON object like `data : JSON.stringify({name : "some name", value : 0})`, and work your way to object you need to send. That might help you identify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON data is invalid.

```
{"jsonAOData": "[{"name":"sEcho"...
```

A JSON string starts with the `"` character and ends at a matching `"` character (unless it's escaped as `\"`). Your string starts at `[{` and ends there. The characters after that are invalid (`name`).

If you want the string to be passed as is, you'll actually need to "re-JSONify" it. First, you'll create a JSON string which you want to pass to the service (`jsonAOData`). Then you'll create a new object which will be passed to the WCF service (and that object needs to be JSONified as well) - see below.

```
var jsonAOData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
var inputBody = JSON.stringify({ jsonAOData: jsonAOData });
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: sSource,
    data: inputBody,
    success: function (msg) {
        fnCallback(msg.d);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Still having issues with the return, but that'll be easy for me to figure out (obviously, my ASMX returned an object with a "d" property, but the new one isnt quite the same and all the data inside it isnt similar, but that part i should be good to get right).

Thanks alot!

Comment: Yep, i changed my "msg.d" to "$.parseJSON(msg.GetRequestsResult)" and all is working as it was before now!" Thanks again M. Figueira!